# How do I add a 3D sprite over a TMX background using Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

We have been working on sample game, in which we want to show a 3D sprite on a background loaded from a `.tmx` file. But the 3D sprite is never showing up, though we tried setting `tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1)`.

This is a sample of our code:

```
CCTMXTiledMap tileMap = new CCTMXTiledMap();
tileMap->initWithTMXFile("map.tmx");    
tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1);
//tileMap->setGlobalZOrder(-1000);
this->addChild(tileMap, 0);

//Sprite3D player = Sprite3D::create("player.c3b");
auto player = Sprite3D::create("player.c3b");
player->setScale(10.0f);
player->setPosition3D(Vec3(200, 500, 0));
this->addChild(player, 1);
```

But the 3D sprite is never showing up.

We have also raised an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/13386).